# Posts containing a specific tag and a category in one permalink

Tags: permalinks

I have posts containing a specific tag and a specific category. For example:

10 posts have "orange" as tag and also belong to "banana" category.

How can i get a permalink: domain.com/tag/category/ containing posts which has this tag AND category in the url? ( for example: domain.com/orange/banana/ ).

I know i could create a specific page with a custom query containing both tag and category. But i have thousands of pages to create, so this is not a good solution.

Creating a permalink for Something like domain.com?cat=1&tag=banana ( this example doesn't work ) would be a better idea.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this help you? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627032/wordpress-url-for-showing-post-by-both-category-and-tag)

Comment: Hello, Yes it does. Thanks a lot.